# Check email address in twig

Tags: twig

How can I check that a string is valid email address in twig template ?

For example, in this code:
`{% set usernameType = (#Check user.username is email#) ? 'email' : 'number' %}`

I need if user.username is a valid email address, usernameType set as email, otherwise set as number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig is executed at the server side so if you want to validate email you should use javascript at client side like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/4450882
in the server side you should use php or python to make this verification.
php validation: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/filter.examples.validation.php
python validation: https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
my view files extension is ".twig.html", so I cant use php codes!
How can I call javascript function in twig tags ?

Comment: you can use the block {% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('PathDuFichier/yourfile.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="your_URL"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // your code
    </script>
{% endblock %}